# MongoClient connect() callback is never invoked

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes

No matter what I try callback of MongoClient.connect() is never called. Have tried several alternatives but nothing seems to make the callback function invoked. I am using node.js mongodb driver 2.1.6 and Express routes. Below is the directory structure:

```
/
node_modules/
exampleServers/
    routes/
        mongo.js
        notes.js
```

Below is the code for mongo.js which am trying to invoke from notes.js for getting DB connections

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

var state = {
  db: null,
}

exports.connect = function(url, done) {

  if (state.db) return done()
  console.log("***REACHES UPTO HERE");
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      console.log("***NEVER REACHES HERE");
    if (err) return done(err)
    state.db = db
    done()
  })
}

exports.get = function() {
    console.log("state.db" + state.db);
  return state.db
}

exports.close = function(done) {
  if (state.db) {
    state.db.close(function(err, result) {
      state.db = null
      state.mode = null
      done(err)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Same problem here